# ListView not getting displayed using simple BaseAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

I've tried all the options and stuck on this since two days. This is the code. Plz help.
The `lvContacts` handler is its self null when i run the code. Even if i resolve this problem it does not display the `listview`.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    Cursor mCursor=null;
    Adapter adContact=null;
    ListView lvContacts;
private static final int TLIST_LOADER = 0x01;
private PAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.i("test", "Yes");
        setContentView(R.layout.view_pager_layout);
        lvContacts=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvContacts);
         String[] projection= { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER

            };

            mCursor=getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
            int phoneNumberIndex = mCursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
            ArrayList alContacts=new ArrayList();


            do {
                alContacts.add(mCursor.getString(1)+ "  "+ mCursor.getString(2));
            }while(mCursor.moveToNext());
            adContact=new Adapter(alContacts, this);
        initialisePaging();
        Log.i("test", "Yes");
        lvContacts.setAdapter(adContact); 

    }

    private void initialisePaging() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<Fragment> fragment=new Vector<Fragment>();
        fragment.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragArrList.class.getName()));
        fragment.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragDialog.class.getName()));
        adapter=new PAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager(),fragment);    
        ViewPager pager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        Log.i("test", adapter.getCount()+"");
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**Adapter.java**

```
    public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context mCtx=null;
    ArrayList mData=null;

    static int i=0;
    Adapter(ArrayList data, Context ctx) {
        mData=data;
    mCtx=ctx;       
}

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(convertView==null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator=((FragmentActivity)mCtx).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView=inflator.inflate(R.layout.row,null);

        }
         TextView tv=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        String name=mData.get(position).toString();
        tv.setText(name);
        return convertView;

    }

}
```

**LogCat**

```
    01-04 23:32:23.309: E/AndroidRuntime(3534): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-04 23:32:23.309: E/AndroidRuntime(3534): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.contatcsnew/com.example.contatcsnew.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-04 23:32:23.309: E/AndroidRuntime(3534):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2083)
01-04 23:32:23.309: E/AndroidRuntime(3534):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2108)
01-04 23:32:23.309: E/AndroidRuntime(3534):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
01-04 23:32:23.309: E/AndroidRuntime(3534):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1204)
01-04 23:32:23.309: E/AndroidRuntime(3534):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-04 23:32:23.309: E/AndroidRuntime(3534):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-04 23:32:23.309: E/AndroidRuntime(3534):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4904)
01-04 23:32:23.309: E/AndroidRuntime(3534):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-04 23:32:23.309: E/AndroidRuntime(3534):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-04 23:32:23.309: E/AndroidRuntime(3534):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
01-04 23:32:23.309: E/AndroidRuntime(3534):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
01-04 23:32:23.309: E/AndroidRuntime(3534):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-04 23:32:23.309: E/AndroidRuntime(3534): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-04 23:32:23.309: E/AndroidRuntime(3534):     at com.example.contatcsnew.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:59)
01-04 23:32:23.309: E/AndroidRuntime(3534):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
01-04 23:32:23.309: E/AndroidRuntime(3534):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
01-04 23:32:23.309: E/AndroidRuntime(3534):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2047)
01-04 23:32:23.309: E/AndroidRuntime(3534):     ... 11 more
```

//view_pager_layout.xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: Post code of adapter class

Comment: Did you put arraylist in your adapter?

Comment: I've arrayList in my adapter.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the list. You are not able to get the contacts maybe. What is the `size()` of mData? Is it empty?

Comment: and I recommend you to use AsyncTask to do database related operations... (any tasks which takes some considerable time)...

Comment: Debug and check hether yout adapters getview is called or not, also check that you have something in arrayList

Comment: getView is getting called and arraylist is having the data. There is no trouble wid the database.

Comment: logCat is giving nullpointerexception at lvContacts.setAdapter(adContact);

Comment: may be (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvContacts); is returning null...

Comment: how about to check `logcat` first?

Comment: exactly... (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvContacts); is returning null...I have no idea why?

Comment: show us the contents of your view_pager.xml file

Comment: shouldnt getItem return mData.get(position) instead of null? also shouldnt this line convertView=inflator.inflate(R.layout.row,null);  be changed to convertView=inflator.inflate(R.layout.row,parent, false);?

Comment: also try instatiating LayoutInflator this way: layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mCtx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

Comment: dont use BaseAdapter or ArrayAdapter when you have a Cursor, in this case use one of the  subclass of CursorAdapter

Comment: @J.Kowalski there is no problem with the line convertView=inflator.inflate(R.layout.row,null)...

Comment: I made those changes and tried. Same error. #nullpointerexception. and i'm not getting why base adapter cant work...its for the list view

Comment: post your pager adapter as well

Answer (score 0):

your `view_pager_layout.xml` does not have a listview so `findViewById(R.id.lvContacts)` is returning null.

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

You must be having this list in one of the pageritems.

If you have `views` as pager items you need to wait for `initializeItem` to be called before you can access listview. Better get the reference of the list view inside PagerAdaper.

And if you have fragments as pager items get the reference of the list in Fragment and set adapter in that.

Comment: but i want listview in activity_arraylist.xml. Isn't htere any method to get its view?

Comment: are you inflating  activity_arraylist.xml in fragment??

Comment: exactly...in FragArrList.java

Answer (score 0):

check out my comments.

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 // wrong implemetation
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
// wrong implemetation
    return 0;
}
```